# Mysql syntax error in Hackerrank - Top competitors

Tags: mysql, syntax

```
With Joined as(Select s.hacker_id, s.score as _score, difficulty_level, s.challenge_id from Submissions s INNER JOIN Challenges ch ON s.challenge_id = ch.challenge_id),

Joined_2 as (Select j.hacker_id, COUNT(DISTINCT j.challenge_id) as cnt from Joined j INNER JOIN Difficulty d ON j.difficulty_level = d.difficulty_level AND _score = score group by hacker_Id) 
Select h.hacker_id, name from Joined_2 j INNER JOIN Hackers h ON j.hacker_id = h.hacker_id order by cnt desc, hacker_id asc;
```

Here's the link to the problem:  [Top competitors](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/full-score/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

Error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'Joined as(Select s.hacker_id, s.score as
> _score, difficulty_level, s.challenge_i' at line 1

Comment: Please add the full error message.

Comment: The error message indicates that hackerrank mysgl version does not support CTEs what result do you get from select version()? Also questions should be self contained - no links please especially to sites which require registration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hackerrank's mysql version is old; too old to support CTEs.
Use subqueries instead:

```sql
Select h.hacker_id, name
from (
  Select j.hacker_id, COUNT(DISTINCT j.challenge_id) as cnt
  from (
    Select s.hacker_id, s.score as _score, difficulty_level, s.challenge_id
    from Submissions s
    INNER JOIN Challenges ch ON s.challenge_id = ch.challenge_id) j
  INNER JOIN Difficulty d ON j.difficulty_level = d.difficulty_level
  AND _score = score group by hacker_Id) j2
  INNER JOIN Hackers h ON j2.hacker_id = h.hacker_id) x
order by cnt desc, hacker_id asc
```

Disclaimer: Didn't check for errant commas or brackets etc, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Seems like the problem. It says 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1. I'm using Mysql 8.0+. Thanks :D

Comment: 'Hackerrank's mysql version is old; too old to support CTEs' - is it https://support.hackerrank.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500002392722--Execution-Environment-and-Samples claims version is 8.0.20? which is a bit unsettling.